# Adding new row to table is not working using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to add/remove new table row `<tr>` which holds some form elements, on click using jquery. I have tried to develop the jquery code using some tutorials but my code is not working. I cannot add or remove any row.

Though I have provided the code below if you still want to see the code on jsfiddle, please check this link : [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xtyFh/)

Could you please tell me where I am doing wrong?
Thanks :)

HTML

```
 <h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>
  <table class="dynatable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Account Name</th>
                <th>Debit</th>
                <th>Credit</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>

     <tbody id="p_scents">

         <tr>
        <td><select name="type" id="type">
              <option value="Debit">Debit</option>
              <option value="Credit">Credit</option>
              </select> 
             </td>

             <td><select name="accounts" id="accounts">
    <option value="">SELECT</option>
    <option value="One">One</option>
    <option value="Two">Two</option>
       </select> </td>

      <td><input type="text" name="debit_amount" id="debit_amount" /> </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="credit_amount" id="credit_amount"/></td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Jquery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents tr').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
        ('<tr>
           <td> <select name="type" id="type">
               <option value="Debit">Debit</option>
              <option value="Credit">Credit</option>
             </select> </td>

         <td> <select name="accounts" id="accounts">
              <option value="">SELECT</option>
              <option value="One">One</option>
              <option value="Two">Two</option>
             </select>  </td>

        <td><input type="text" name="debit_amount" id="debit_amount"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="credit_amount" id="credit_amount"/></td>
   <td><a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></td></tr>').appendTo(scntDiv);

            i++;
            return false;
     });

      //Remove button
         $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('<tr>').remove();
                    i--;
            }
            return false;
          });
       });
   </script>​​
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a working example, including remove row functionality: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/scumah/xtyFh/8/).

And this is the resulting JS:

```
var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
var i = $('#p_scents tr').size() + 1;

$('#addScnt').click(function() {
    scntDiv.append('<tr><td><select name="type" id="type"><option value="Debit">Debit</option><option value="Credit">Credit</option></select></td><td><select name="accounts" id="accounts"><option value="">SELECT</option><option value="One">One</option><option value="Two">Two</option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="debit_amount" id="debit_amount"/></td><td><input type="text" name="credit_amount" id="credit_amount"/></td><td><a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></td></tr>');   
    i++;
    return false;
});

//Remove button
$(document).on('click', '#remScnt', function() {
    if (i > 2) {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        i--;
    }
    return false;
});​
```

First, your HTML had a couple of syntactical problems (solved in the fiddle). You where using the [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/), function wrong, and the selector in your last function ('$(this).parents('').remove();') needed to be just 'tr'.

And nothing much :P

Comment: should I use `.live` event or `.on` ? According to Tats_innit .on event as .live is deprecated from the latest version of Jquery

Comment: @black_belt Oops, my fault, you should definitely be using `.on()`. I updated the answer :D

Comment: @black_belt, I'm sorry, but I don't get what you meen with 'for add but' :/ What do you want me to add?

Comment: I am sorry, there was a typing mistake.. What I was trying to say is please replace `.live` event with `.on` in `$('#addScnt').live('click', function() {` in your code above. THanks

Comment: Damn, I just replaced it in the last call xD Thanks for pointing that out, sorry I didn't realize it :P

Comment: Anyway, I just realized there's no need of using `on` in the first `click` since that link isn't changing in the DOM. `.click()` Is the way to go in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Hiya **working demo** `:)` http://jsfiddle.net/9S2Sc/ **full working version** http://jsfiddle.net/UBxTf/

there are quite a few thing needed attention: **also** please use `.on` event as `.live` is deprecated from the latest version of Jquery,

please see rest of the code below.

hope this help the cause

**code**

```
$(function() {

    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');

    var i = $('#p_scents tr').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').on('click', function() {

        $('<tr><td> <select name="type" id="type"><option value="Debit">Debit</option><option value="Credit">Credit</option></select> </td><td> <select name="accounts" id="accounts"> <option value="">SELECT</option> <option value="One">One</option><option value="Two">Two</option> </select>  </td><td><input type="text" name="debit_amount" id="debit_amount"/></td><td><input type="text" name="credit_amount" id="credit_amount"/></td><td><a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></td></tr>').appendTo(scntDiv);


                i++;
                return false;
         });
});

          //Remove button
             $('#remScnt ').on('click ', function() { 
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents(' < tr > ').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
              });
         ​
```

Comment: -1: The remove function does not work. +1 to reflect your update.

Comment: @black_belt sure here you go full working version `:)` http://jsfiddle.net/UBxTf/ glad I can help

Comment: @Monkieboy please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/UBxTf/ lol tell me man -1 is not  constructive `:)`

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function should be used like this:

```
$('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
scntDiv.append('<tr>
           <td> <select name="type" id="type">
               <option value="Debit">Debit</option>
              <option value="Credit">Credit</option>
             </select> </td>

         <td> <select name="accounts" id="accounts">
              <option value="">SELECT</option>
              <option value="One">One</option>
              <option value="Two">Two</option>
             </select>  </td>

        <td><input type="text" name="debit_amount" id="debit_amount"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="credit_amount" id="credit_amount"/></td>
   <td><a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></td></tr>');

            i++;
            return false;
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another error exists in the function to remove the rows. It must be

```
$(this).parents(' tr ').remove();
```

without `<` and `>`

A tip: the browsers Firefox, Chrom and Safari provide an error console for Javascript. So you can see error messages.

Comment: By the way I found another mistake of yours. You added form fields with same name and id. Ageneral rule is that id must! be unique within the page. You can avoid it, if you add just a counter to that attribute.